# how to copy a list of list and vertically append them in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to define a function that takes a Picture of type [[Char]] and replicates each element. But then it needs to take that replicated new image and make a copy of it and append it vertically. I am able to use "replicate" and copy each element twice, but I'm not exactly sure how to copy the new image. What I did is I just appended replicate twice, but that only "appends" horizontally, as opposed to vertically. Here is my code:

```
type Picture = [[Char]]

picture::Picture 
picture = ["#", ".", "#"]

replicating::Picture->Picture
replicating pic = concatMap (replicate 2) pic ++ concatMap (replicate 2) pic

main = do
    print(replicating picture)
```

Ultimately I am trying to achieve this image:

```
##..##
##..##
```

So far I have only this:

```
##..####..##
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are just missing a newline `"\n"` in between your two `concatMap`s

Comment: You need a `\n` character. Or you make a list of lines and use the `unlines` function.

Comment: So where exactly should I place the "\n"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
import Data.List

type Picture = [[Char]]

picture::Picture 
picture = ["#", ".", "#"]

replicating::Picture->String
replicating pic = intercalate "\n" $ replicate 2 $ 
                           concat $ concatMap (replicate 2) pic
```

which you can then call and show the output from `main` as follows-

```
main = do 
    putStrLn (replicating picture)
```

It isn't 100% clear to me from the question that the output you are looking for is a String, but if so, you need that extra `concat` in there to convert type `[String]->String`.

Once that is done, you duplicate it and finally, `intercalate` acts sort of like `concat`, but lets you insert something between each string being concat'ed (which in this case is the '\n' that others mentioned in the comments).

---

As @Bheklilr mentioned in the comments, `intercalate "\n"` can be simplified to `unlines`....  If you need something else between the lines, use `intercalate`, else `unlines` is much cleaner.

Comment: @bheklilr- Good point, (basically `unlines=intercalate "\n"`, I suppose I should mention that above)....  I tend to use intercalate a lot because often I have something else in between (like a comma at the end of each line, or whitespace indenting after the first line), but that seems not to be the case here, so I will add a comment to the answer.

Comment: The output I am looking for is of type Picture (return of the functin replicating). Picture is a [[Char]]. Now I do get the idea of what you're saying, but I'm not sure how it's going to work. I tried this: replicating::Picture->Picture
replicating pic = intercalate "\n" (concatMap (replicate 2) ++ concatMap (replicate 2) pic). It doesn't work. Can you give me a more specific code please

Comment: @RumenHristov- I'm not clear on what the output should be.  `[[Char]]` is a list of strings (it equals `[String]`).  Do you want the output to be `["##..##", "##..##"]`?  If so, just leave out the unlines/intercalate completely in the expression above.  If not, could you give us the actual output you are looking for written as a Haskell type?

Comment: It is all in the code up there. The function needs to take the passed picture of type Picture, modify it and return it again preserving its type Picture. I have also very explicitly drawn the output that I need and the output that I currently have.

Comment: More specifically: ["#","#",".",".","#","#"]. Now we move to a new line and print out the same thing.

Comment: @RumenHristov- Ultimately, you will need to convert to `String` if your goal is to get the output above, then you should use `putStrLn` instead of `print` (which will display the string quoted and with backslash escapes intact, like "\n" vs an actual newline).  If you just prepend `putStrLn $` to the answer above, it should output what you want.

Comment: Again, I try your suggestions, but my code never compiles. I am not sure where to put the "putStrLn" and what else needs to be changed. Why don't you do an edit to your answer and put the code where you think it needs to go.

Comment: Ok. I think I finally got it. This is how the code should look. Can you put that in your answer please for others to see and then I'll vote the qn answered. Code: replicating::Picture->String
replicating pic = intercalate "\n" $ replicate 2 $ concat $ concatMap (replicate 2) picture

main = do
    putStrLn(replicating picture)